# Move plugin icon in QGIS version 2.19.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, toolbar, icon

Once a new QGIS plugin is selected and loaded from the "manage and install plugins" toolbar selection, the plugin automatically appears somewhere on QGIS' toolbar panels.

Often, the new plugin icon is grouped with other icons and cannot be separated out from its assigned group, which may not be ideal.

If the default placement position is not the one desired, how is it moved to another location?

Comment: Would you be able/possible to upgrade to a more recent version of QGIS?

Comment: do you mean, moving a tool icon from one toolbar to another (e.g. by dragging its icon out of one toolbar into another, or dragging an icon inside its toolbar to change the order of icons ?)

Comment: @whyzar QGIS 2.19.0 is already the newest (dev) version.

Comment: even though I would prefer a built-in solution for this inconsistent handling of plugins in qgis I suggest using the plugin customize toolbars.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As an example of my dilemma, the plugin "Attribute based Clustering" is installed in a group that contains nine others including "coordinate capture," "DFX importer," "GPS tools," et al. If possible, I would like to move "Attribute based clustering" out of its default group and to another location. Attempts using "customize toolbars" were unfruitful.

Comment: The plugins are written in Python, with the source code included. You can look into `__init__.py` and the following modules to see where the icon gets added to, then change that code.

Comment: @CharlesHuett when you say attempts using "Customize toolbars" were unfruitful why was that? Because you weren't able to add it to a toolbar or that you were able to however the "Attribute based Clustering" plugin is still in the Vector tab with the other default group you mentioned? I will post what I have as an answer shorlty.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Plugins tab search for the plugins "Customize ToolBars"

[image]

Then

[image]

Then install the plugin

[image]

The "Customize ToolBars" plugin is under the Plugin tab

[image]

Create new toolbar

[image]

Add the other tools into the new toolbar created

[image]

Here is the new toolbar with custom tools added

[image]

Here is the "Attribute based Clustering" added to the new toolbar that was created through "Customize ToolBars" plugin.

[image]